# How to use CREATE STATISTIC object in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am trying to make different `STATISTIC` objects using different attributes in a database.

#### Problem - 1

My aim is to find the error in selectivity by choosing different attribute combinations. I wanted to compare this results with some other experiments. Here is what I have done,

1. I have made ***each of the attribute combinations*** (nC1, nC2, ..., nC_len_of_attributes). One attribute combination, two attribute combination etc. For example (name), (name, age), (name, age, zip), (age, zip), etc.
2. Made `STATISTIC` objects for each of the combinations using the command `CREATE STATISTICS <name> on <one_attrib_combination> from <table_name>`
3. I ran `ANALYSE` on the table, `<table_name>`.
4. Now I want to run a set of queries on each of this `STATISTIC` objects and get selectivity for each of the `STATISTIC` objects.

How can I go about this problem? I am using `PostgreSQL 10`. Any ideas?

#### Problem - 2

The second problem is, I wanted to know the size of each of these `STATISTIC` objects? How can I find the size of each of the unique `STATISTIC` objects that I have created before?

Thanks in advance for answering my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Purpose for `STATISTICS` is different. You can create extended stats, so that planner can be aware about relations between columns, functions and so on. That way DBA can provide better, dynamic hint for the planner. [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createstatistics.html) for `CREATE STATISTIC` has nice explanation for that.

To see information about that object there is dedicated catalog [pg_statistic_ext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-statistic-ext.html).

To get something you can use `explain analyze`, but I would say - this is dead-end, and choose other path... Sorry for bad news.